# Python - BSON document parsed for one document only

Tags: python, json, bson

I have a BSON document of 62,292,248 bytes size that I want to analyze. I am using the following:

```
import bson
f = open('mybson.bson','rb')
s = f.read()
b = bson.loads(s)
f.close()
```

On the console, when I enter `b` and hit enter, I can see only one document even though `s` has read all of the bytes. I tried with `f.read(62292248)` too; but, `b` seems to have only one document!

What am I missing?

Comment: So, do you have *a* BSON document, or do you have *many* BSON documents stuffed into one file?

Comment: Possibly the latter; as it is a dump from a MongoDB.

Comment: It's ~62MB file, are you sure you are only seeing one file dump in the console? I mean how does your console display so much data?

Comment: I am not seeing the whole file output from `bson.loads()`. Only one document. This is the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like [bson.loads](https://github.com/py-bson/bson/blob/master/bson/__init__.py#L43) are supposed to load exactly one document.

We can decode multiple documents present within a bson as below-

```
with open('mybson.bson', 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
    base = 0
    while base < len(content):
        base, d = bson.decode_document(content, base)
        print(d)
```

Comment: This is by far the most useful answer to this question. I needed to load the son file to list of duct and only this worked. Thanks.